# How to automatically add a dot after the nth character automatically in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to write a textarea in which the user should enter the given latitude in decimal degrees.

For example: 60.45678 or 05.1

What should I do to make a dot appear in the textarea automatically after the second character?

I already have a function to check if the characters are numbers:

```
<script language=Javascript>
        function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;

            return true;
        } </script>
```

Maybe it can be somehow modified so that it would add a dot and check if the first two numbers are smaller than 90?

```
<textarea name="LongitudeEW" placeholder="Longitude East/West." onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></textarea>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do you know how to check the length of the value of a HTML element?

Comment: Strange request. Why not validate the input instead and tell user latitude must be between certain values?

Comment: @charlietfl 

You're right.  It's a much better and simpler way.

Comment: But can fail  if user doesn't enter a leading `0` for values between 0 and 10. You would be placing decimal in wrong place and what about negative latitudes?

Comment: I made buttons that change N/S E/W.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var DECIMAL_REGEXP = /(?<=^.{2}$)/g;

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
    return false;
  }

  target.value = target.value.replace(DECIMAL_REGEXP, '.');

  return true;
}
```

```js
var DECIMAL_REGEXP = /(?<=^.{2}$)/g;

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
  
  if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
    return false;
  }

  target.value = target.value.replace(DECIMAL_REGEXP, '.');
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="LongitudeEW" placeholder="Longitude East/West." onkeypress="return handleKeyUp(event)"></textarea>
```

In case you want to bind to the elements keypress event vs inlining:

```js
// cache the regexp
var DECIMAL_REGEXP = /(?<=^.{2}$)/g;

// ref the textarea
var textrea = document.getElementById('LongitudeEW');

// bind to the keypress event
textrea.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  var target = e.target,
      charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
      
  if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  target.value = target.value.replace(DECIMAL_REGEXP, '.'); 
});
```

```html
<textarea id="LongitudeEW" name="LongitudeEW" placeholder="Longitude East/West."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this library: https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

For example as your requirement. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
<script src="cleave.js"></script>

<input class="input-element" type="textarea" >

<script>
    $(function(){       

        var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
            delimiter: '.',
            blocks: [2, 100],
            numericOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>
```